# What is the difference between cmpq 0,R and testq R,R?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, disassembly

(This is my first post ever on stack overflow, please lmk if I've done something wrong)
I'm currently brushing up on `assembly` code for `C` and doing some sample problems to test my understanding. One multiple-choice practice problem gives a description of the code in `C` and asks you to pick the corresponding `assembly` code. Answers `A` and `C` are clearly wrong. Answers `B` and `D` are identical (I ran them through a text comparison thing to make sure I wasn't missing anything, that's how sure I am that they're identical) except for the following two (greatly simplified) lines:

```
# Answer B
...
6   testq %rax, %rax
7   jle .L3
...
```

```
# Answer D
...
6   cmpq $0, %rax
7   jle .L3
...
```

According to the practice problem, `D` is correct and `B` is wrong.

But from what I understand, shouldn't they calculate the same thing? Here's my reasoning, can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

1. Both `testq` and `cmpq` alter condition codes but not the registers themselves, so nothing but the condition codes should make a difference.
2. `testq S1 S2` will set condition codes according to the calculation `S1&S2`. If `S1==S2` (both `%rax` here), `testq` should set condition codes according to whatever is currently in `%rax`.
3. `cmpq S1 S2` will set condition codes according to the calculation `S2-S1`. If `S1==0`, then `cmpq` should set condition codes according to `%rax-0 = %rax`.

So they're both setting condition codes according to the same thing, the contents of `%rax`. That was enough to really confuse me. I thought maybe looking at the problem at a lower level, specifically in terms of condition codes, might clear things up, but that didn't really help either.

4. This specific jump (jle/jng if you prefer) will jump to `.L3` if `(SF^OF)|ZF` is true.
5. `%rax` is not going to overflow on something&something or something-0, so `OF=0`. Therefore it will jump if SF=1 or ZF=1.
6a. If `%rax` is negative, `%rax & %rax` will still yield a negative, so SF is set and jump occurs. If `%rax` is negative, `%rax-$0` will still yield a negative, so SF is set and jump occurs.
6b. If `%rax` is 0, `%rax&%rax` is 0, so ZF is set and jump occurs. If `%rax`is`0, %rax-0 = 0-0 = 0`, so `ZF` is set and jump occurs.
6c. If `%rax` is positive (and non-zero), `%rax&%rax` will yield a positive (non-zero), so `SF=0` and `ZF=0` and the jump doesn't happen. If `%rax` is positive (non-zero), `%rax-0` will yield a positive (non-zero), so `SF=0` and `ZF=0` and the jump doesn't happen.

Where did I go wrong? From what I understand after thinking about the problem, shouldn't it always be true that

```
testq R,R
```

has the *same logical outcome* as

```
cmpq $0,R
```

(Note: I know almost nothing about efficiency. It's possible one instruction is shorter or more efficient than the other, but I'm primarily concerned with the logical/condition code outcomes here. For real code and not just textbook problems, the computer/gcc will decide which one it thinks is faster later, when it optimizes it to the point of being unreadable.)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you correctly simplified the original lines of code?  Did one of them have a memory operand?  Obviously `test (mem),(mem)` can't work, so you have to use `cmpq $0, (mem)`, or load into a register.  Or maybe there was some other difference, because yes, the linked duplicate is correct that they set FLAGS identically except for AF, and `jle` doesn't look at AF.  (In fact there are no JCC instructions that look at AF, and with `AAA`, `DAA` and other BCD instructions not available in 64-bit mode, I think the only way it's observable is with `pushf` to store RFLAGS.)